# Deployed API returning bad requests status code

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I developed a simple API using .Net core and it locally works as intended. After deployment only the WeatherForecast endpoint is working and the rest results in status 500. I have used code first with EF and enabled migrations during the publish process through VS code.
Any suggestion?

Azure gives me these errors but I am not really familiar with Azure

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fos5u.jpg)

[my code](https://github.com/BlinkAC/RestApi)

[endpoint](https://azgeirr.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast)

**EDIT**: The endpoints are working now, but as I said in a comment below I changed my local db connection string (see my appsettings.json in git) by the one that azure gives me and everything is working correctly but, if you have alredy filled you db with many records probably that's not the entire solution

Comment: You need to share the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: The endpoint you shared returns the JSON response successfully... where is the 500 error?

Comment: The enponit that I shared is the only working (WheatherForecast) the endpoints not working are https://azgeirr.azurewebsites.net/api/Products

Comment: This error normally occurs due to a “NullReferenceException” wherein you attempt to read a parameter value that hasn’t been defined yet or is set to null.

Comment: Please refer [Troubleshooting 5xx Errors with Azure APIM services](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/troubleshooting-4xx-and-5xx-errors-with-azure-apim-services/ba-p/2115752) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code, I see that you have added connection string of the localdb. Did you update this in configuration on app service?

I am pretty sure that your application is unable to connect to the database and hence the 500 : internal server error

Also you should add appsettings to .gitignore so that it is not pushed to a remote public repository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think thats my problem but as I said, I am not familiar with azure and since the beggining the part of the connection strings confuses me because in  vs code i got this config but I am not sure if I did it correctly https://imgur.com/a/iTpvcLe

Comment: Well everything works now changing the connections string in appsettings.json file by the one that azure gives me, but doing this the azure db has no data (in this case don't care because I used to have only 5 records) so I think is not what I wanted at the beggining